# SQL query or script to search and replace all the old names in a database with new ones from another database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, replace

Hello I am working on a SQL database

Using Microsoft SQL server 2008 R2
And Microsoft SQL Server management studio

I have a Database Called **FixedNamesDb**
On the database there is one table called **All**

It is similar to this (this is an example):

```
OldNames        NewNames
------------+---------------+
tom G         Thommas Grady               
Kate F        Kateline Farwell               
John S        Jhon Smith
```

In another Database Called **DescriptionDb** There is lots of tables **Table1**, **Table2**, **Table3** ....

Foreach Oldname in the **FixedNamesDb** I need to search all the tables in the **DescriptionDb** and if the oldname appears in any field i need to replace it with the newName

I search all the tables in **DescriptionDb** for a field containing "John S" and replace it with "Jhon Smith"

Any help on how to do this automaticaly? Usding a script, a query or something else.

More info:

- Each Name Appears only one time in one of the tables of **DescriptionDb**
- All the names appears (there is no name that does not exists)
- All the names are located in the Second Row of the table (Row where ID=2)

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: if the two databases in the same server you can access each database tables using `DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName`, if your database in different servers you will need to make `linkedserver` between the two servers

Comment: The two database are in the same server. But my question is how can I search the entire table field by field to check if it is equal to the name I need to change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this script for each table that needs to be updated.

```
UPDATE
  DescriptionDb.Table1
SET
  Name = FN.NewName
SELECT
  FixedNamesDB.[All] AS FN
WHERE
  Name = FN.Oldname
```

The following script can find all tables and columns. Using a programming or scripting language loop through all tables and columns replacing `Table1` and `Name` in the above script with all iterations of the script below.

```
SELECT
  TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLES.TABLE_NAME 'TABLE_NAME',
  COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME,
  COLUMNS.DATA_TYPE,
  COLUMNS.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS,
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE
  COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = TABLES.TABLE_NAME
  AND TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DescriptionDb'
ORDER BY
  TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA,
  TABLES.TABLE_NAME,
  COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME
```

Comment: The names in the DescriptionDb are not located in a single column. Thanks for helping

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Are they split by first and last name? Are they randomly scattered across columns?

Comment: Randomly scattered across columns. Thanks

Comment: This is exaclty what I need. Can you show me how to link them together? how can I use the iteration? sorry I'm not very experienced in sql. Thanks a lot

Comment: Depending what programming/scripting language you have at your disposal will determine the exact implementation. Basically though, you will use the results of the second query to populate the first through the use of a loop.

Comment: Based on the column types in your database you will likely exclude numeric, datetime and other similarly valued columns for a performance boost and to avoid type mismatch errors.